# SwiftUI Type '()' Cannot Conform To 'View'

Tags: swiftui

I've created two state variables in my code, and I want to modify them into another value. But why the error always shown if I modify the variables?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var ketupatTest = [
        KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton(), KetupatButton()]
    @ObservedObject var score = Score()
    var columns: [GridItem] =
            [.init(.adaptive(minimum: 100, maximum: 100))]
    @State var height = 0
    @State var width = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView{
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns){
                    ForEach((0...100), id: \.self){i in
                        ButtonView(score: score, viewModel: ketupatTest[i], size: 100)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            Text(String(score.value))
            GeometryReader{
                geo in
                VStack{
                    
                    Text(String(Int(geo.size.height)))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please include code, and not images of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, or read by screen readers. The issue is that you can't (and shouldn't) set `self.height` in the middle of the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign a value to `self.height` within your VStack as it only expects `View`s.

Try to set this height in the `VStack`'s `onAppear` instead:

```
GeometryReader { geo in
    VStack {
        Text(String(height))
    }
    .onAppear {
        self.height = Int(geo.size.height)
    }
}
```

Edit: This might not be the best solution. See @jnpdx's comment below.

Comment: Setting the height from `GeometryReader` in `onAppear` like this won't be reliable and won't adjust if, say, the interface is rotated. This needs something like a `PreferenceKey` to be effective.